# Where is my mistake in this answer to Project Euler #58?

Tags: ruby

I am solving project [Euler question 58](http://projecteuler.net/problem=58). Here a square is created by starting with 1 and spiralling anticlockwise in the following way (here is side length equal to 7:

```
37 36 35 34 33 32 31
38 17 16 15 14 13 30
39 18  5  4  3 12 29
40 19  6  1  2 11 28
41 20  7  8  9 10 27
42 21 22 23 24 25 26
43 44 45 46 47 48 49
```

The question is to find out when we keep spiralling around the square, when the ratio of primes in the diagonals and the amount of numbers in the diagonal is smaller than 0.10.

I am convinced I have the solution with the code below (see code comments for clarification), but the site states that the answer is wrong when I am entering it.

```
require 'prime'

# We use a mathematical derivation of the corner values, keep increasing the value till we find a ratio smaller 
# than 0.10 and increase the grid_size and amount of numbers on diagonals each iteration

side_length = 3 # start with grid size of 3x3  so that we do not get into trouble with 1x1 grid
prime_count = 3 # 3, 5, 7 are prime and on a diagonal in a 3x3 grid
diagonal_size = 5
prime_ratio = 1 # dummy value bigger than 0.10 so we can start the loop

while prime_ratio >= 0.10
  # Add one to prime count for each corner if it is prime
  # Corners are given by n2 (top left), n2-n+1, n2-2n+2, and n2-3n+3
  prime_count += 1 if (side_length**2).prime?
  prime_count += 1 if (side_length**2-side_length+1).prime?
  prime_count += 1 if (side_length**2-2*side_length+2).prime?
  prime_count += 1 if (side_length**2-3*side_length+3).prime?
  # Divide amount of primes counted by the diagonal length to get prime ratio 
  prime_ratio = prime_count/diagonal_size.to_f
  # Increase the side length by two (full spiral) and diagonal size by four
  side_length += 2 and diagonal_size += 4
end

puts side_length-2 #-2 to account for last addition in while-loop

# => 26612
```

It probably is wrong and site is right. I am stuck on this problem for quite some time now. Can anyone point me the mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`side_length += 2 and diagonal_size += 4` should be at the beginning of the loop.

Couldn't check, I do not have ruby installed, but I can reproduce the same problem on my python solution.

Comment: Also, I think you can remove `prime_count += 1 if (side_length**2).prime?`, since a square number will never be prime : )

Comment: Wow that somehow reduced the execution time by more than 50%. /edit Probably because the value is never prime and numbers that are not prime take longer to check with `prime?` function from the library.